# Problem with growing JTable rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm making a code in which I have a `JTable` with my own made table model(it is not default one) into which I have to fill the data while the program is executing. So the number of rows also increases as the data increases (diff. at diff. times). I don't want to show unnecessary rows, I mean not to show empty rows by creating a large stack well in advance.

Since the array size is fixed (of which I thought of doing with first), could anybody help me with the best way possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ArrayList<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. It internally adjusts the size of the data structure as needed.

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

arrayList.add(new Integer[]{1, 2});
arrayList.add(new Integer[]{3, 4});
arrayList.add(new Integer[]{5, 6});
```

Comment: The following ain't working for me.please suggest.

    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    arrayList.add(new String[]{"a", "b"});

Comment: The following ain't working for me.please suggest.

    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    arrayList.add(new String[]{"a", "b"});


Actually your code

    arrayList.add(new Integer[]{1, 2});

also not working.It is saying package arrayList ain't exist.

Comment: @Pankaj make sure you have `import java.util.ArrayList;` included. see the this sample code and output here http://ideone.com/bxavf

Comment: Also consider `List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); list.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b")))`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add new rows to the model when you need to. In a simple case you can just use DefaultTableModel (used by JTable by default) or if it isn't flexible enough, implement your own model by extending AbstractTableModel. Something like this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.addColumn("Number");
model.addColumn("Number + 1");

//Add pointless numbers to model
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    model.addRow(new Integer[] { i, i + 1});
}

JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

The model will notify the JTable of changes when you modify it. If the concept of models seems foreign to you, I suggest reading the official introduction to the JTable component: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html